# Add libcurl Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, libcurl, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

i need to include libcurl in my unreal engine project, i need to use it in game, how i can do it? i have tried standard tutorial for include curl in visual studio, but not work.
the compiler return error on other portion of code if i include curl with following code

```
#include <curl\curl.h>
```

I have tried also to change separator to / but nothing, i have read about thirdbart library but how i can add curl?
other questione, look in Visual Studio project, curl.h is included in extetrnal reference for Engine project, but not in Game project.. how i can include?

EDIT

i have included the directory
C:\Lib\curl\builds\libcurl-vc-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\include\
lib direcotry
C:\curl\builds\libcurl-vc-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\

when include curl show this error when i compile:

[image]

If i remove #include curl\curl.h from code it compile fine.

Comment: (1) always put the exact error message in your question.  (2) add the directory above `curl` to the Visual Studio include paths.

Comment: i have edited and include image of errors,..

Answer (score 0):

I have solved!, You must add the path of library in VC++ tab in , includes directory and lib directory, after you must add this line in you build.cs

```
  PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add("path to lib file");
 PublicIncludePaths.Add("path to includes directory");
```

have nice day!